# spring rest not returning json object - getting 404

Tags: json, spring, rest, annotations

i have looked for a few days now and with no luck.. i am getting a http 404 and can not find out what i'm missing, why its not picking up my mapping. am i doing it wrong?

I am using Spring Rest and trying to return a json object using @ResponseBody annotation. Please help! I am using jackson-core-2.2.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar, and jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar. Here is my code and my server logs are below. appreciate the help!

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>app</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

</beans>
```

Address.java

```
package com.app.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    //getters and setters

}
```

AddressController.java

```
package com.app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.app.domain.Address;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/rest")
public class AddressController {

    @RequestMapping(value="address", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Address addressEntry(@RequestParam(value="street", required=true) String street, 
            @RequestParam(value="zip", required=true) String zip){

        Address addressRequest = new Address();
        addressRequest.setStreet(street);
        addressRequest.setZip(zip);
        return addressRequest;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="address/{street}/{zip}", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Address addressEntry2(@PathVariable(value="street") String street, 
            @PathVariable(value="zip") String zip){


        Address addressRequest = new Address();
        addressRequest.setStreet(street);
        addressRequest.setZip(zip);
        return addressRequest;
    }
}
```

I am using Jboss AS7 and when the server starts up, here is the logging

```
19:09:22,052 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-8) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
19:09:22,430 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
19:09:22,604 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped "{[/rest/address],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[application/json],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.app.domain.Address com.app.controller.AddressController.addressEntry(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
19:09:22,607 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped "{[/rest/address/{street}/{zip}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[application/json],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.app.domain.Address com.app.controller.AddressController.addressEntry2(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
19:09:22,640 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
19:09:23,102 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,103 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address.*] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,104 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,105 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/{street}/{zip}] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,106 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/{street}/{zip}.*] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,107 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/{street}/{zip}/] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,124 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-8) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1169 ms
19:09:23,173 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/app]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
19:09:23,173 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-8) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
19:09:23,177 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 16 19:09:23 EST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
19:09:23,180 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-8) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
19:09:23,250 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
19:09:23,290 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped "{[/rest/address],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[application/json],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.app.domain.Address com.app.controller.AddressController.addressEntry(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
19:09:23,291 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped "{[/rest/address/{street}/{zip}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[application/json],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.app.domain.Address com.app.controller.AddressController.addressEntry2(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
19:09:23,471 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,472 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address.*] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,473 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,473 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/{street}/{zip}] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,474 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/{street}/{zip}.*] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,475 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-8) Mapped URL path [/rest/address/{street}/{zip}/] onto handler 'addressController'
19:09:23,507 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-8) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 333 ms
19:09:23,514 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /app
19:09:23,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
19:09:23,516 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 6174ms - Started 245 of 324 services (78 services are passive or on-demand)
19:09:23,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "appEAR.ear"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define what the method should produce.
you can do that by setting produce attribute for the RequestMapping annotation.

Example:
@RequestMapping(value="address/{street}/{zip}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })

Comment: i took your input and added produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, removing headers="application/json" attribute, then i get a http 406. when i put both the headers AND produces, i still get the 404..

Comment: does it help if i show my request headers and response headers from my browser? the Content-Type doesnt say "application/json" anywhere. not sure if that makes a difference, if it does, how do i fix it?                                                    Response Headers
Content-Length 956
Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8
Date Fri, 17 Jan 2014 03:55:29 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1                        
                                                                        Request Headers
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: as you can see, the header field accept doesn't include application/json and since the method is returning JSON you get a 406. so if you need json you need to define accept application/json in accept header field or if you can live with xml just do this @RequestMapping(value="address/{street}/{zip}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })

Comment: when i have @RequestMapping(value="/address", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}). i dont get the 406, but a 404.. 13:26:55,520 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/rest/address/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'. what am i missing from the above code?

Comment: I think this is wrong, but I'm not sure 
headers={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your headers attribute  value to

```
"Accept=application/json"
```

Comment: from my understanding, putting headers={"Accept=application/json"} means the client's brower has to be able to accept application/json. do you know of a way to make/force the client's browser accept application/json?